# AWS EC2 IP change affecting running jobs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I launch AWS EC2 instances with a `userData` field that runs the desired initialization jobs. One of the initialization commands is to run an infinite time background process. My question is that since AWS EC2 instances change IP addresses frequently, will my infinite time background process be killed upon a change in that instance's IP? I am not changing the instance's state after I launch it. When I initialize my instances, the jobs are working fine, I just don't know whether that behavior will continue upon an IP change since I don't have a way for rigorously testing this.

Comment: Where are you getting this information that an EC2 instance changes IP frequently? The IP only changes when the server is shutdown and then subsequently started again.

Comment: I was running some batch jobs on my EC2 server for 6 hours when I SSH into my server. I did not modify the instance state, and then my SSH connection was terminated because of change in IP and the instance was still running.

Comment: Probably your own IP address changed. Running EC2 instances don’t change their IP address by themselves.

Comment: I may have been mistaken. So you are sure that if an EC2 instance is running and its session state never gets modified, then its IP address remains constant?

Comment: Yes. I've written an answer describing the exact behavior of EC2 in regards to private and public IP addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSH connection termination might be due to your ISP having changed your own public IP address, or a similar networking issue on your or your provider's side, and not the EC2 instance having changed. An EC2's IP address only changes under certain well-defined circumstances that I'll describe below:

**An EC2 instance's private IP address:** Once an EC2 instance is launched, it's assigned a private IP address at boot time. An instance's private IP address will never change during the lifetime of that instance.

**An EC2 instance's public IP address:** When an instance is launched, you control whether it receives a public IP or not. The public IP address never changes automatically, but can change under the circumstances described below.

- AWS releases your instance's public IP address when it is stopped, hibernated, or terminated. Your stopped or hibernated instance receives a new public IP address when it is started.
- AWS releases your instance's public IP address when you associate an Elastic IP address with it. When you disassociate the Elastic IP address from your instance, it receives a new public IP address.

**To answer your original question:** You don't need to worry about an EC2 instance regularly changing its IP address because as long as it keeps running and you don't explicitly change the associated IP address yourself, the IP address will remain static.

If you want to retain a public IP address that persists even after hibernating, stopping, or terminating the instance, you can attach an Elastic IP address.

For more information see: [What are Elastic IP addresses, and how do I use them?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/intro-elastic-ip-addresses/#:%7E:text=An%20Elastic%20IP%20address%20is,Allocating%20an%20Elastic%20IP%20Address.)